# Map flags enum property to separate table

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Imagine a class like this:

```
public class MyEntity : Entity
{
    public virtual States States { get; set; }
}

[Flags]
public enum States
{
    None,
    State1 = 1,
    State2 = 2,
    State3 = 4,
    State4 = 8
}
```

I want to map it to this table:

```
TABLE MY_ENTITY
ID: PK
STATES_ID : FK to MY_ENTITY_STATES

TABLE MY_ENTITY_STATES
ID: PK
IS_STATE1_SET (bit)
IS_STATE2_SET (bit)
IS_STATE3_SET (bit)
IS_STATE4_SET (bit)
```

Is this possible?

This is a legacy scenario, I can't change the database.

---

As per request, here is some sample data:

Table MY_ENTITY

```
ID | STATES_ID
---+----------
14 | 35
```

Table MY_ENTITY_STATES

```
ID | IS_STATE1_SET | IS_STATE2_SET | IS_STATE3_SET | IS_STATE4_SET
---+---------------+---------------+---------------+--------------
35 | 0             | 1             | 0             | 1
```

This should lead to a value of `States.State2 | States.State4` in the `States` property in the `MyEntity` instance with the ID 14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a two step solution.

First, use [join](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-join) to bring the MY_ENTITY_STATES record, and then write a `IUserType` that converts the flags to columns.

Check [here](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/understanding-nhibernate-type) for an example.

Comment: Thanks, that looks great. I will test it tomorrow. Can you please provide a sketch of the mapping in Fluent NHibernate?

Comment: .Join(something... Map(theproperty).Type(thetype)... something like that :-) I don't use fluent; you'll have to figure it out with intellisense.

Comment: I am not quite sure, how to do this. In the link you provided the implementation of `ICompositeUserType` is introduced as a mapping between a class with two properties and two columns. But I have only an enum with no properties. What would I return e.g. for `PropertyTypes` or `PropertyNames`?

Comment: I believe you can return a simple property (call it "Value") of type States.

Comment: In the mean time, I tried to use an `IUserType` instead of an `ICompositeUserType`. It works quite well, see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9924033/572644). However, I still have a problem with the join, please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923915/join-table-in-mapping-with-inverse-fk).

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple `IUserType` implementation to achieve the mapping. An implementation of an `ICompositeUserType` is not necessary:

```
public class StatesUserType : IUserType
{
    private static readonly SqlType[] _sqlTypes = {
           NHibernateUtil.Int16.SqlType, NHibernateUtil.Int16.SqlType, 
           NHibernateUtil.Int16.SqlType, NHibernateUtil.Int16.SqlType  };

    public Type ReturnedType
    {
        get { return typeof(States); }
    }

    public SqlType[] SqlTypes
    {
        get { return _sqlTypes; }
    }

    public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
    {
        var result = States.None;
        if (((short)rs[names[0]]) == 1)
            result |= States.State1;
        if (((short)rs[names[1]]) == 1)
            result |= States.State2;
        if (((short)rs[names[2]]) == 1)
            result |= States.State3;
        if (((short)rs[names[3]]) == 1)
            result |= States.State4;

        return result;
    }

    public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return;
        if (value.GetType() != typeof(States))
            return;
        var states = (States)value;
        cmd.Parameters[index] = states.HasFlag(States.State1);
        cmd.Parameters[index] = states.HasFlag(States.State2);
        cmd.Parameters[index] = states.HasFlag(States.State3);
        cmd.Parameters[index] = states.HasFlag(States.State4);
    }

    public bool IsMutable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public object Assemble(object cached, object owner)
    {
        return cached;
    }

    public object DeepCopy(object value)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object Disassemble(object value)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        return object.Equals(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(object x)
    {
        return x.GetHashCode();
    }

    public object Replace(object original, object target, object owner)
    {
        return original;
    }
}
```

The mapping needs to look something like this:

```
Map(y => y.States).Columns.Add("IS_STATE1_SET", "IS_STATE2_SET",
                               "IS_STATE3_SET", "IS_STATE4_SET")
                  .CustomType<StatesUserType>();
```