# Join table in mapping with inverse FK

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Assume I have two tables:

Table MY_ENTITY

```
ID: PK
OTHER_ID: FK to table OTHER
```

Table OTHER

```
ID: PK
COL: The column I want
```

My entity looks like this:

```
class MyEntity : Entity
{
    public virtual Column { get; set; }
}
```

My auto-mapping override looks like this:

```
mapping.IgnoreProperty(x => x.Column);
mapping.Join("OTHER", x => x.KeyColumn("ID").Optional()
                            .Map(y => y.Column, "COL");
```

This works fine and executes without problems, but the join is wrong.

It creates an SQL statement that joins the PK of `MY_ENTITY` to the column specified in `KeyColumn` in the table `OTHER`. Something along the lines of:

```
select ... from MY_ENTITY e left outer join OTHER o on e.ID = o.ID
```

However, I need the join to be like this:

```
select ... from MY_ENTITY e left outer join OTHER o on e.OTHER_ID = o.ID
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to add an `OtherId` property to `MyEntity` (it doesn't have to be public; it's just for mapping) and use `PropertyRef` in the Join Key mapping (that's the method name in mapping by code; it's `property-ref` in XML, you'll have to look it up for Fluent)

Alternatively, map `Other` as an entity and use a `Reference` in `MyEntity`. You can cascade all, so it get's persisted/deleted together with MyEntity.

Then, just project the referenced property (which will not be mapped in MyEntity):

```
class MyEntity
{
    public virtual PropertyType Property
    {
        get
        {
            EnsureOther();
            return Other.Property;
        }
        set
        {
            EnsureOther();
            other.Property = value;
        }
    }

    void EnsureOther()
    {
        if (Other == null)
            Other = new Other();
    }

    public virtual Other { get; set; }
}

class Other
{
    public virtual PropertyType Property { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The projection is a nice idea and it directly solved my next question: "How to correctly persist entities with a joined table that has a PK"? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use a `References` (`many-to-one`) mapping instead.

```
References(x => x.Other, "OTHER_ID")
    .Fetch.Join()
```

Comment: Yes, that's what Diego also suggested.

Comment: Yeah I saw an answer pop up as I was completing this.